# What type of trailer do I need for my Granada 24 sailboat?

Tags: boats, sailing

I'm about to get a [Granada 24](http://sailboatdata.com/viewrecord.asp?class_id=3916) sailboat and I can't really figure out what type of trailer I need. It would be awesome if someone could explain to me what I need to know to choose the right trailer.

These are the specs of the boat:

Hull type: Mono hull

Keel type: Fin keel (I guess)

Length: 7,20 m

Width: 2,52 m

Draft: 1,25 m

Size: 10,1 m2

Weight: about 1600 kg (without load)

There is very little information on this boat.

Do I need to use a trailer made to measure, or can I use any trailer that can carry any boat of a specific category within its range of specs (keel type, weight, and dimensions)?

[image: Granada 24]
[image: Granada 24 schema]

[Picture source 1](http://sailboatdata.com/viewrecord.asp?class_id=3916)
[Picture source 2](https://warmlicht.wordpress.com/sy-mathilda/)

Resources regarding [hull, sail and keel types](http://www.boats.com/resources/sailing-101-sailboat-types-rigs-and-definitions/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Do I need to use a trailer made to measure, or can I use any trailer
>   that can carry any boat of a specific category within its range of
>   specs (keel type, weight, and dimensions)?

You don't need a specific trailer. Just make sure that it's a 2,7 tons trailer with a keel tub.

An example would be the "Wick braked tandem trailer 2700 kg":

[image]

[From "Wick Trailer"](http://85.158.4.112/wick-bootstrailer-responsive/trailer-segelboottrailer-2.html#collapseGTDT-2700) (caution, you've to scroll down and choose the 2700 kg version)

For reference, there is a guy selling this type of a Granada 24 exactly with this trailer on [eBay](https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-granada-24/k0) (actually it's from a trademark which doesn't exist anymore but Wick continues to build them):

> Der Trailer ist ein 2,7 to NELBACH-Trailer Bauj. Okt.2000, TÜV
>   Aug.2018. ebenfalls sehr gepflegt. (sollte man den Trailer nicht
>   gebrauchen, kann das Boot auch ohne dieses erworben werden.

Translated:

> The trailer is a 2,7 t Nelbach from October 2000. (...)

This is going to look somewhat like this:

[image]